# Get parameter values from method at run time

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection, methods, parameters, runtime

I have the current method example:

```
public void MethodName(string param1,int param2)
{
    object[] obj = new object[] { (object) param1, (object) param2 };
    //Code to that uses this array to invoke dynamic methods
}
```

Is there a dynamic way (I am guessing using reflection) that will get the current executing method parameter values and place them in a object array? I have read that you can get parameter information using MethodBase and MethodInfo but those only have information about the parameter and not the value it self which is what I need.

So for example if I pass "test" and 1 as method parameters without coding for the specific parameters can I get a object array with two indexes { "test", 1 }?

I would really like to not have to use a third party API, but if it has source code for that API then I will accept that as an answer as long as its not a huge API and there is no simple way to do it without this API.

I am sure there must be a way, maybe using the stack, who knows. You guys are the experts and that is why I come here.

Thank you in advance, I can't wait to see how this is done.

**EDIT**

It may not be clear so here some extra information. This code example is just that, an example to show what I want. It would be to bloated and big to show the actual code where it is needed but the question is how to get the array without manually creating one. I need to some how get the values and place them in a array without coding the specific parameters.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. You already have the parameters in an array in the code you showed. What is the problem with that?

Comment: Why do you need this? When you're inside the method, you already know the parameters and can easily put them in an array (as your example shows).

Comment: The keyword `params` might be useful if you what you want is receiving  a list of parameters of unknown length in an array : `public void MethodName(params object[] parameters)`

Comment: This is just that, an example. It would be to bloated to show the actual code where it is needed but the question is how to get the array without manually creating one. Edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection you can extract the parameters name and metadata but not the actual values :

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.testMethod("abcd", 1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void testMethod(string a, int b)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.StackTrace st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
            StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(0);
            ParameterInfo[] pis = sf.GetMethod().GetParameters();

            foreach (ParameterInfo pi in pis)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(pi.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So it is impossible at run time to get the values?

Comment: You might want to use something like PostSharp AOP style approach,